# Can happiness be measured quantitatively? such that an amount of money can buy

Tags: truth, happiness, hedonism

There is a cliche, which is often used by the middle class, saying that

> happiness cannot be bought

and supporting their thought by stating how many rich people suicide or constantly go to psychologists. However, **if someone's only goal is to become rich and compete in wealth, would not he considered a happy person once he has achieved that?**

Comment: I'm missing the concrete philosophical question here. Please have a look at our recent questions and the [help/on-topic]. If you can [edit] your question to make it fit, please do so, and we can reopen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A person who managed to become rich and therefore happy hasn't bought happiness. "Buying happiness" would mean giving away money in exchange for happiness. This person hasn't been giving away money in exchange for happiness.

And a person who has only one goal in life wouldn't be automatically considered a happy person when that goal is achieved. They would be considered a person who achieved their goal, that's all.

Quite the opposite, people who have only one goal in life may be very happy while they are working hard to achieve that goal, and when it is achieved, they have nothing to achieve, no goal, and may be unhappy because the goal in their life is gone.